# How to handle json dictionary in Liquid templates?

Tags: json, liquid, dotliquid

I am rather new to Liquid templates, but I don't seem to find a way to loop through a dictionary in json and access the different values.
Disclaimer: I am using the Shopify Liquid Preview extension for VSCode.

**Input json file:**

The input file contains two properties: `CustomerId` and `Transactions`, which is the 'dictionary' property, containing a list of KeyValuePairs.  I want to loop through the Transactions collection and output the `TransactionValue` properties.

```json
{
    "CustomerId": 13,
    "Transactions": {
        "1": {
            "Id": "1",
            "TransactionValue": 1000
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "2",
            "TransactionValue": 207.47
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```html
<h1>Customer 13</h1>
<ul>
    <li>1000</li>
    <li>207.47</li>
</ul>
```

**Current Attempt**

I can easily loop the collection, but then it's not clear to me on how I can access the actual properties of the current transaction.  None of the following work.  When just outputting the variable, it gets printed like this: `1,[object Object]`

```
<ul>
{% for trx in Transactions %}
    <li>{{trx}}</li>
    <li>{{trx.Key}}</li>
    <li>{{trx.Value}}</li>
    <li>{{trx.Object}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I don't really have control over the input json, so I was hoping to find a good way on making this work as is.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most Liquid flavors it should be possible to reference an object field by name like this:

```
{{ Transactions["1"].TransactionValue }}
```

Then it is a matter of getting all known transactionIds from somewhere. If they're not available as an array, then the dirty solution could be to parse raw incoming JSON, e.g. like that:

```
{% assign transactionIds = Transactions | split: "\"Id\": \"" %}
<ul>
{% for id in transactionIds %}
    {% if id[0] != "{" %}
        {% assign realId = id | split: "\"" | first %}
        <li>
            {{ Transactions[realId].TransactionValue }}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't like the string parsing of the json obviously (and no, I don't know the id's upfront), so any better option would always take my preference.